# Python - Extracting text from field using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract some data from a field as shown below:

```
['com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@6626d945[id=342,rapidViewId=24,state=ACTIVE,name=Project_A,goal=,startDate=2019-06-14T04:34:06.823Z,endDate=2019-06-27T04:34:00.000Z,completeDate=<null>,sequence=342]']
```

I tried regular expression but get an error

```
error: unterminated character set at position 0
```

where I stored the value above to a variable `val`

```
re.search(r'[id=(.*?)",,',val).group(1)
```

Comment: To match `[` literally, you need to escape it `\[` otherwise engine expects a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex instead:

`re.search(r"id\=(\d+)", val).group(1)`

In plain terms, you're looking for `id=something`, where something are some digits. Maybe the `id` is preceded by an opening square bracket, and maybe the digits and followed by a `,`, but maybe not? Search for what you know is true.